# Can not figure out how to run a file stored in a variable found with 'find' in shell script in Terminal on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, shell, find

The code I have at the moment is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/Users/{User}/Documents/jarfiles/"
runnable_game=$(find . -type f -name 'game\..*\.jar')
echo $runnable_game
eval $runnable_game
```

in my Documents folder I have a folder jarfiles and within that folder there is only 1 jar file, although if possible only make it select the first file found.

The goal is to execute this file. for example: `/Documents/jarfiles/game.1234.jar` should be run.

for debug I put an echo in there, but the echo returned nothing, a blank line.

I have some programming skill, but I am not professional and in no way used to shell scripts or terminal command line magic. (I program in Java, C and such...)

Any idea to make a script that finds a file and runs it?

**to clarify:**
 I don't know the filename in advance any .jar file to that format should be run, basically I download a file to that directory which is in that format

Comment: Maybe just `java -jar /Users/$USER/Documents/jarfiles/game1234.jar`?

Comment: to clarify I don't know the filename in advance any .jar file to that format should be run, basically I download a file to that directory which is in that format

Comment: Suppose there are **10** `.jar` files. How  exactly would you pick the file to run? Explain the logic. You probably do not need the `find` command at all.

Comment: I still need to find the file in that folder cause there may be other jar files or other directories etc. the contents are unknown, but if the .jar file with that format exists. it should be run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a `jar` file you know is there but you don't know the exact name,
you can use a simple shell wildcard,
you don't need the `find` command:

```
java -jar game*.jar
```

If you want to execute only the first file found, then `find` can be indeed useful:

```
find . -name 'game*.jar' -exec java -jar {} \; -quit
```

Comment: on the second example using find: Is this way of writing the command conventional, and should I use that above `java -jar $(find . -name 'game.*jar')` which in my case worked in the same way, or is there a difference?

Comment: The version I gave you is safer, in that it will work even if you have strange characters in the path of the file. It's the generally recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Correct shell code to run 'game' + *any string* + 'jar'

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/Users/{User}/Documents/jarfiles"
java -jar $(find . -name 'game.*jar')
```

`game\..*\.jar` escaping using \ seemed to not work
this will find files starting with game and ending with jar, not game. and .jar, which is not a problem (at the moment).

Comment: No this is not regex, `.*` doesn't work in glob. It should be `game*jar`

Comment: @anubhava Thank you very much that will definitely help

Comment: well it was an answer, might be slightly a work around, but it definitely worked for me, but I should still verify @janos 's answer because it is more accurate. And if it wasn't an answer to the question, then I must have asked the question wrongly. My mistake in any case.